# When is it illegal to remove myself as an observer for my keys?

Tags: ios, cocoa, key-value-observing

I'm encountering a problem in my app. For reasons of convenience, it's easier for my app delegate to observe its own properties. However, when removing the app delegate as an observer, I receive an error.

I've boiled it down to a small code sample and the result (*shown later*).

My question is, when is it illegal to remove myself as an observer for my own keys and how would a typical cocoa developer get around the problem in the following example:

from this code...

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface Thing : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) Thing * next;
@property (nonatomic, strong) id value;
@end

@implementation Thing
@synthesize next,value;
+(Thing*)thing
{
    return [[Thing new] autorelease];
}
@end

@interface AppDelegate ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) Thing * thing;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window, thing;

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application

    Thing * thing2 = [Thing thing];
    thing2.value = @"hello";

    Thing * thing1 = [Thing thing];
    thing1.next = thing2;
    self.thing = thing1;

    [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"thing.next.value" options:0 context:NULL];
    [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"thing.next" options:0 context:NULL];

    Thing * thing3 = [Thing thing];
    thing3.value = @"goodbye";

    self.thing.next = thing3;
}

- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    NSLog(@"value did change for keyPath '%@'", keyPath);
    [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"thing.next.value"];
    [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"thing.next"];
}

@end
```

I get this result...

> 2011-11-03 13:32:02.123 TestKVO[11637:707] value did change for
>   keyPath 'thing.next'
>
> 2011-11-03 13:32:02.124 TestKVO[11637:707] Cannot remove an observer
>   <NSKeyValueObservance 0x103828250> for the key path "next.value" from
>   <Thing 0x10381d970>, most likely because the value for the key "next"
>   has changed without an appropriate KVO notification being sent. Check
>   the KVO-compliance of the Thing class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem lies in the fact that you register for two sources of notification that are inclusive.

Instead you should:

- Only register for `@"thing.next"`
- Inside the notification processing method, unregister for `@"thing.next.value"` on the old `@"thing.next"` value (found in the `change` dictionary), then register for the `@"thing.next.value"` on the new `@"thing.next"` value (also found in the `change` dictionary).

This way, the bindings remain consistent when the `@"thing.next"` key-path changes.

Comment: This is most likely correct. when you register `thing.next.value`, your app is keeping a weak reference (i.e. not retained) to `thing.next`. You then change `thing.next` so KVO gets confused because `thing.next` has changed thus changing `thing.next.value` but no KVO notification was sent for `thing.next.value` changing. Phew. this can get confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Couple things:

1) are you implementing your own setters? if so, you need to make sure they conform to KVO by sending `willChangeValueForKey:` and `didChangeValueForKey:` appropriately. Look for the section on KVO compliance in Apple's Key-Value Observing Programming Guide.

EDIT: The above was intended for you to check the overall compliance of your class. @sam is correct that you don't need `willChange...` and `didChange...` in custom setters unless you have disabled automatic notifications.

2) rather than have your object observe it's own properties (a little strange IMHO) you could implement custom setters that do whatever you want in the object when the value is changed.

Comment: I agree with overriding setters probably being a better route, but he shouldn't have to call `willChangeValueForKey:` / `didChangeValueForKey:`.  In fact if he did he would probably have his methods firing twice because kvo is automatic unless you turn it off even if you write your own setters.  See [KVO Compliance](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOCompliance.html) and `automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey:`.

Comment: @sam is correct regarding automatic KVO. I meant my comment to check the compliance of the class. I'll edit my answer.